# Tika- Pandas bridge to export PDF content to Excel?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, pdf, apache-tika

I would like Python to read a PDF file ("Spain.pdf" containing 11 columns and 59 rows, one of which is a header) and export its contents to Excel.

There are **many** PDF-Excel threads on here, but none that I consulted address the concept of a bridge from parsed Tika content to Pandas data frames that write to Excel.

I've searched this site (and elsewhere), talked to a couple of programmers, and consulted some manuals and books. I can't R_every_FM because, as a novice, I don't know where to focus: i.e., do I want to flush content into a Pandas data frame?

From SO and Sweigart (2015) I found Tika, Tabula, and PyPDF2 to parse PDF content. Tika worked best for me. (The Tabula app is great for manual dumps, but the Python module doesn't run for me.) I used the following code:

```
from tika import parser
raw = parser.from_file('spain.pdf')
print(raw['content'])
```

which prints clean content to my console.

I'm trying to transfer this content into a data frame, which I could then export to Excel via XlsxWriter (or a similar module):

```
import pandas as pd
dataSpain = pd.DataFrame({'Survey': ["Key","ISO","Country","Region","Province","Comarca","City","Name","Age","Gender","Hospital"]})
datatoexcel = pd.ExcelWriter("FromPython.xlsx",engine='xlsxwriter')
dataSpain.to_excel(datatoexcel, sheet_name='Sheet1')
datatoexcel.save()
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction? Any thoughts would be appreciated. Many thanks for your attention.

Code is written in Atom 1.45 and run via Windows PowerShell 5.1. Environment is Python v3.8.0 on a Microsoft Surface 2 laptop running Windows 10 Home v1903.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the main issue you're experiencing is that the Pandas ExcelWriter code you're using is asking for another [Python library](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/) called `xlsxwriter` to serve as an engine (as opposed to the default `openpyxl` library) which you might not have installed as it is independent of Pandas.

So first step would be to make sure you install it ( `pip install xlsxwriter`) 
I ran the following code in a terminal/command line based on your post and it worked fine:

```
import pandas as pd
dataSpain = pd.DataFrame({'Survey': ["Key","ISO","Country","Region","Province","Comarca","City","Name","Age","Gender","Hospital"]})
with pd.ExcelWriter('FromPython.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    dataSpain.to_excel(writer)
```

If it doesn't work, the next step would be to share the error you're getting. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, Lee-On! I did have xlsxwriter installed, but I missed the "with ~ as writer:" combination. However, when I export to excel, the content that's in my console doesn't get flushed to Excel. Only the column headers that I have defined appear in my Excel worksheet.

Comment: When you print(raw['content']) you see a representation of the string that Tika returns, but that string is not "ready" to be transformed into a DataFrame. I believe the issue you're experiencing is that you aren't transforming the string into a data type that Pandas can turn into a DataFrame `ndarray (structured or homogeneous), Iterable, dict, or DataFrame`  (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html).